# PuTTY Fatal error: Couldn't agree on host key algorithm

Tags: linux, putty

I'm trying to connect to a new system with PuTTY and am seeing the following:

Fatal error: Couldn't agree on host key algorithm (available: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256)

[image: putty fatal error]

Checking available algos on the server:

```
acoder@client ~ $ nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 server.name.here

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-16 10:33 EDT
Nmap scan report for server.name.here (1.1.1.1)
Host is up (0.018s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 8.0 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms: (7)
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp256
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp384
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp521
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
|       diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
|       diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
|       diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
|   server_host_key_algorithms: (3)
|       rsa-sha2-512
|       rsa-sha2-256
|       ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
|   encryption_algorithms: (6)
|       aes256-gcm@openssh.com
|       aes256-ctr
|       aes256-cbc
|       aes128-gcm@openssh.com
|       aes128-ctr
|       aes128-cbc
|   mac_algorithms: (6)
|       hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
|       hmac-sha2-256
|       hmac-sha1
|       hmac-sha2-512
|   compression_algorithms: (2)
|       none
|_      zlib@openssh.com
```

Here's what's available on my client machine:

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes

```
acoder@client ~ $ ssh -Q key
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Ciphers

```
acoder@client ~ $ ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
blowfish-cbc
cast128-cbc
arcfour
arcfour128
arcfour256
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

MACs

```
acoder@client ~ $ ssh -Q mac
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
hmac-ripemd160
hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

KexAlgorithms

```
acoder@client ~ $ ssh -Q kex
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 16):

You're overlooking that PuTTY and ssh (OpenSSH) are two completely separate programs. They don't share any code; they don't use any common crypto library. The `ssh -Q` lists don't tell you anything about what PuTTY can support.

I think the problem is that your PuTTY version is too old. Out of the signature methods offered by the server, ECDSA signatures (`ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`) need at least PuTTY version **0.68**, while the RSA-SHA2 methods (`rsa-sha2-*`) will only be
available in the next PuTTY release (0.75).

The cause of this is that OpenSSH servers have disabled support for the old SHA1-based `ssh-rsa` signature algorithm very recently (they still use the same RSA keys, but only through SHA2-based signatures), while support for DSA keys has been removed several years ago.

Comment: Thanks. It appears I am on Putty 0.73 as of now. The issue is actually involved with Filezilla, which I understand uses Putty for connecting.

Comment: I was using putty 0.73 and upgrade to latest version 0.80 did not solved the issue. But after using `apt update && apt upgrade` on vnc connection of my remote server the issue was solved.